# Performing basic raster to shapefile conversion?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, erdas-imagine

I am a novice when it comes to GIS. I am currently trying to use ERDAS imagine to classify habitat types using landsat 8 images. I'm able to run a supervised classification with the product being a TIFF file. I then opened this tiff file in ArcMap. Now I'm having a hard time projected this imagery over a base map in ArcMap or even extracting coordinates from the imagery with the respective classified habitat.

I tried to convert the raster to a vector/shapefile in Erdas but was given an error saying that the input file had to be thematic.